# Array Indexer to string builder

Tags: c#

Code :

```
            string[] X = Regex.Split(X, ",");
            string[] A = Regex.Split(A, ",");
            string[] B = Regex.Split(B, ",");
            string[] C= Regex.Split(C, ",");
            string[] D = Regex.Split(D, ",");



            for (int i = 0; i < splitfirsts.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}",
                      X[i], A[i], B[i], C[i], D[i]);               
            }
```

The information inside string[] :

> X = 1,2,3
>
> A = 4,5,6
>
> B = 7,8,9
>
> C = Adam,Mark,Tom
>
> D = 16,21,88

The Result will Return :

> 147Adam16
>
> 258Mark21
>
> 369Tom88

What i trying to achieve :

> string newstring = 147Adam16258Mark21369Tom88

It's there anyway to achieve it with a simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] X = Regex.Split(X, ",");
string[] A = Regex.Split(A, ",");
string[] B = Regex.Split(B, ",");
string[] C= Regex.Split(C, ",");
string[] D = Regex.Split(D, ",");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < splitfirsts.Length; i++)
{ 
  sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}",
          X[i], A[i], B[i], C[i], D[i]);             
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: I do console.writeline(sb);

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without using string builder. If you want to just output `147Adam16258Mark21369Tom88`, you can use `Console.Write`. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitfirsts.Length; i++)
        {

            Console.Write("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}",
                      X[i], A[i], B[i], C[i], D[i]);
        }
```

But, if you want to store it, you can use `StringBuilder` by this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < splitfirsts.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}",
              X[i], A[i], B[i], C[i], D[i]);

        }

Console.Write(sb);
```

Hope it helps!